# Force quit then restart, all apps still active iOS 9

Tags: ios, applications

I am running iOS version 9.0.1. This problem has been happening since iOS 9 came out. If I double click the home button, then swipe up on my open apps, it used to close them out for good. When I would restart, there were no open apps. However, now when I force quit every app and restart, they are all open again. Even if I close out of everything and maybe have Twitter open and a game, when I restart, I have a ton of apps open when I only had two before restarting. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: I just found out that this happens on both my iPhone and my iPad.  Both running 9.0.1.

Comment: This is an issue I am noticing. I would recommend to tell apple about this at apple.com/feedback

Comment: I've never been in any way convinced that this was ever good practise anyway. What does it hope to achieve? Memory-saving? The oldest apps are gradually dropped out of RAM anyway. Data saving? Switch off Background App Refresh. Battery saving? They're inactive, except for my last point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list of apps shown after double clicking the home button is not only the list of open apps but also the list of apps most recently used. Or in other words: not all apps in the list are actually "open" (whatever this means on iOS anyway).

Comment: That would make a lot of sense now that I think about which apps were always showing up!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

As long thought & finally confirmed once & for all by Apple's Senior vice-president, Craig Federighi, this week - it serves no purpose whatsoever to quit backgrounded apps.

Source :  BBC News -

## [Apple customer goes to the top for iPhone battery answer](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-35782865)

[image]

> The head of Apple's operating system iOS confirmed that open but
> unused apps do not affect iPhone battery life after a customer emailed
> boss Tim Cook. The customer from Ohio, known as Caleb, asked Mr Cook
> whether closing down "multitasking apps" improved battery life and
> whether it was something the chief executive did himself.
>
> Senior vice-president Craig Federighi replied "no and no".
>
> However, other smartphone batteries can benefit from app closure.
>
> Microsoft advises Nokia Lumia owners to close apps that aren't in use
> [on a web page about extending battery life.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/product/lumia635/smartguidance/?action=singleTopic&topic=B-GUID-DB7FD3C1-122C-43CE-8AFD-8034FC707A61-8_10_1)
>
> Android creator Google [suggests identifying and closing apps that are
> not often in use](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6090612?hl=en-GB) but warns that frequent use of its Overview
> device manager to do this will in itself drain the battery.
>
> "You can view and optimise your device through closing running apps
> and uninstalling unnecessary apps," said Samsung [in an announcement
> about a new "smart manager" app for the Galaxy 6.](https://news.samsung.com/global/smart-manager-the-way-to-keep-your-galaxy-smartphone-as-good-as-new-always)
>
> While many Apple users do shut down apps in the belief it extends the
> iPhone battery this is not advice explicitly given by the firm itself.
>
> It only recommends [disabling apps from carrying out background
> refreshes](http://www.apple.com/uk/batteries/maximizing-performance/) in a list of tips about saving power.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved it.
Hopefully it'll work for you.

1. Double click home button.
2. Swipe up to close all apps.
3. Open a single app.
4. Now double click  home button but do not swipe up.
5. Press the power button. But do not swipe to power off.
6. Press and hold the home button till you're back at the desktop.
7. Double click home button again.
8. Press the power button again.
9. This time swipe it off.
10. Turn it back on.

After signing in, you should only have one app opened instead of 32 which is what I had ever when I rebooted.

Answer (score -2):

I've been struggling with this very big on both iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus after upgrading to iOS 9.

I finally figured out how to solve this problem without whiling the device and 'setting up as new.'

Solution: 'Reset All Settings'

That's it. Good as new. No content or media erased (differs from 'Erase All Content'), just retyping a few passwords for iCloud, wifi and recustomizing your ringtones and notification settings.

Was dreading having to wipe my device and Setup As New...