# Are the apps opened in CarPlay still running after disconnecting phone from the car?

Tags: iphone, car-integration, ios

I use CarPlay a lot. For navigation I use either Google Maps or Waze (or both). Because they are both from Google I used to close them (swipe them up from the open app list) after I disconnect my phone from the car to reduce their spying activities.

I recently installed iOS 13 and it introduced a concept of using different app on the phone screen and different app on the car screen. So now after getting out of the car I don't see them in the open app list even if I used them when driving.

And here's the question: are they not running anymore? Is there a different way to force-quit them? And does quitting them actually change anything?

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever need to to force quit apps when you're done with them.
[Evidence provided by Apple themselves a few years ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231045/85275)

If you don't tell a SatNav you've finished your journey*, then it will keep actively navigating.

Otherwise, just unplug your phone & off you go.

*Some of them insist on continuing to navigate to some pre-determined spot 50m from where you actually wanted, so until you pass through its destination point it will still keep on trying.

Incidentally, apps can be told from settings not to be allowed to use your location &/or track anything whilst not active, & Google apps can also be told from your Google account not to track you.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer my question nor has it any relation to (new) CarPlay. And the quoted answer says about battery life only…

There are basically two questions I would like to get answer for:
1. Are the apps still running after unplugging from CarPlay even if they are not seen in "task manager"? My assumption is yes because iOS displays a blue header saying that an app is using my location and when I click it I am redirected to Waze/GMaps.
2. If yes to above, is there a different way to force closing them?

Comment: 1. Answered in my 2nd paragraph. 2. Why?? Paranoia?